# No se pudo instalar el paquete Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, nuget

Quiero instalar el paquete de microsoft.Graph pero no me deja, me lanza el siguiente error.

> Install-Package : No se pudo instalar el paquete 'Microsoft.Graph
> 4.44.0'. Está intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' como destino, pero el paquete no
> contiene referencias de ensamblado  o archivos de contenido
> compatibles con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en
> contacto con el autor del paquete. En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
>
> - Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 4.44.0
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: ¿De casualidad estás usando net core?

Comment: Hola, no... no es Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu mensaje de error indica que estas en un proyecto .NET Framework 4.5.2, y el nuget que intentas utilizar/descargar no lo admite

> Está intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' como destino, pero el paquete no contiene referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido compatibles con dicho marco.

Si vas a verificar el nuget [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) veras que solamente soporta .NET  Framework 4.6.1 o superior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, opciones

¿si o si necesitas .NET Framework 4.5.2? Si es asi no lo podras utlizar directamente... hay alternativas. Pero son todas comunicandote con otra app  o servicio. puedes migrar a .NET Framework alguna version mas reciente? o incluso utilizar .NET 6

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Versiones y dependencias de .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)
- [Migración a .NET Framework 4.8, 4.7, 4.6 y 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Gracias, no sabía que no soportaba la versión que tenía.